# nginx serve static index on root directory next to flask API

Tags: nginx, flask

Trying to serve static files and an API in from the same servername.
I want to visitor to be directed to `servername/index.html` when they browse `servername/`

Currently `servername/` is being processed by Flask instead.
Both API and static exist in the same dir.

`nginx.conf`:

```
server {

# path for static files
root /var/www/html;
location / {
  # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
  index index.html;
  try_files $uri @proxy_to_app; <--- gunicorn here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `$uri/` in `try_files` worked:

```
location / {
  # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
  index index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy_to_app;
}
```